# static initialization of a class used by asp.net-- how long will the initialized values last?

Tags: asp.net

We're writing a class we'll use in our asp.net site.  This class will pull down some json using HttpClients and such, and use it to provide information to other clients.

Some of this information will change very infrequently and it doesn't make sense to query for it on each client request.

For that reason I'm thinking of making a static constructor in this new class for the slow-changing information and stashing the results in a few static member variables.  That'll save us a few HttpRequests down the line-- I think.

My question is, how long can I expect that information to be there before the class is recycled by ASP.Net and a new one comes into play, with the static constructor called once more?  Is what I'm trying to do worth it?  Are there better ways in ASP.Net to go about this?

I'm no expert on ASP.Net thread pooling or how it works and what objects get recycled and when.

Typical use of the new class (`MyComponent`, let's call it) would be as below, if that helps any.

```
//from mywebpage.aspx.cs:
var myComponent = new MyComponent();
myComponent.doStuff(); //etc etc.  
//Method calls like the above may rely on some 
//of the data we stored from the static constructor call.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static fields last as long as the AppDomain. It is a good strategy that you have in mind but consider that the asp runtime may recycle the app pool or someone may restart the web site/server.

As an extension to your idea, save the data locally (via a separate service dedicated to this or simply to the hard drive) and refresh this at specific intervals as required. 
You will still use a static field in asp.net for storing the value, but you will aquire it from the above local service or disk ... here I recommend a System.Lazy with instantiation and publication options on thrread safe (see the constructor documentation).